# If a weak preference relation is complete and transitive, why is the strict preference relation negatively transitive?

Tags: microeconomics, preferences

My textbook says that "if a weak preference relation is complete and transitive, the strict preference relation MUST be asymmetric and negatively transitive". Now, I think I understand why it must be asymmetric - all strict preference relations are asymmetric, correct? However, I don't understand why it is negatively transitive. If the weak preference is transitive, couldn't the strict preference also be transitive?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at: [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion here stems from misinterpreting negative transitivity to mean "not transitive". But that's not what it means. It is perfectly possible for a binary relation to be both transitive and negatively transitive, as is the case here with the strict preference relation.

**Definition 1.** A binary relation $\mathcal{R}$ is *transitive* if: $$x \mathcal{R} y \text{ and } y \mathcal{R} z \implies x \mathcal{R} z.$$

**Definition 2.** A binary relation $\mathcal{R}$ is *negatively transitive* if: $$x \not\mathcal{R} y \text{ and } y \not\mathcal{R} z \implies x \not\mathcal{R} z.$$

(Those are forward slashes over the $\mathcal{R}$'s meaning "not". The LaTeX "not" here isn't quite working as well as I'd like.)

The strict preference relation $\succ$ is both transitive *and* negatively transitive.

- It is *transitive* because $(x \succ y \text{ and } y \succ z)$ implies $x \succ z.$
- It is *negatively transitive* because $(x \not\succ y \text{ and } y \not\succ z)$  is equivalent to $(y \succsim x \text{ and } z \succsim y)$, which, by the transitivity of $\succsim$, implies $z \succsim x$ or $x \not\succ z$.